# ngrok on Ubuntu Core

Tags: software-installation, snap, ubuntu-core, curl

I'm using Ubuntu Core for the first time, running a RocketChat server on a Raspberry Pi 3.

In order for anyone outside my home network to be able to use it, I'm trying to install ngrok per instructions in https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.RaspberryPi:

```
curl https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.19_linux_arm.zip -o ngrok.zip unzip ngrok.zip cd ngrok ./ngrok http 3000
```

However, I just get this:

```
-bash: curl: command not found
```

I've been trying to install either curl or ngrok, and failing at both. <s>Can I only install things that exist in the snap catalogue?</s> How do I solve this? Where can I read more?

Edit: OK, so I can only install snaps, right? Is there any other good solution for anyone outside of my home network to access the RocketChat server?

Answer (score 0):

Taking from [HTTP Request Without curl or wget](//stackoverflow.com/q/48853480) you can install classic bash shell with

```
snap install classic --edge --devmode
sudo classic
```

after start the shell:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Unfortunately, at this moment http://dl.ngrok.com doesn't work but in `apt-cache` you can find `ngrok-server`. I hope is the same.

Answer (score 0):

the link to the ngrok zip file is changed,

register to ngrok and follow the instruction to download the correct executale file (for me and you on this page https://ngrok.com/download , linux arm executable)

after unzipping it, follow the instruction on the same page to add your auth token and to start ngrok

`./ngrok authtoken myauthtoken`

`./ngrok http 3000`